# Why are randomly-generated distributions from numpy.random and scipy.stats so different that their probabilities don't sum properly?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, probability-distribution, scipy.stats

When randomly generating random numbers using the `numpy.random` package, and the `scipy.stats` package, why is the histogram (total probabilities) generated by the former package have such large values with a maximum near 4, whereas the latter's histogram is more reasonable with a maximum much less than 1.

[image]

Probability distributions are supposed to only sum to 1, with no individual probability exceeding 1. Even though the `scipy` generator looks more tame, it still doesn't sum to 1. How can I make both generators from `numpy.random` and `scipy.stats` behave the same way, i.e. have no single probability exceeding the maximum of 1?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand, randn
from scipy.stats import norm, johnsonsu

n = 100
x = randn(n)*.1
y = johnsonsu.rvs(a = 2.55, b= 2.25, size=n)

for i in [x, y]:
    print(sum(i))
    pd.Series(i).plot.kde()
```

Besides the plot, the output from a single run shows the sums of the randomly generated vectors to be wildly different:

```
0.9035925193845973
-144.49886490879146
```

Comment: You are working with continuous distributions, meaning that you are not dealing with probabilities but with probability densities. For those it's not the sum but the integral that is one. In particular, values larger than 1 are perfectly normal.

Comment: How can `randn` and `johnsonsu` be corrected to a level playing field

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make both generators from `numpy.random` and `scipy.stats`... have no single probability exceeding the maximum of 1?

This is already in the comment, but let's put it in an answer: for a continuous distribution, the probability *density* function is allowed to exceed 1; it is the integral of the probability density function over the support that must equal 1.

> Besides the plot, the output from a single run shows the sums of the randomly generated vectors to be wildly different:

There is no reason to expect the sums of random samples from different distributions to be similar to one another. Even two samples of the same size from the same distribution can be very different (depending on the distribution).